# Coding <a> under <ul> confusion

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my codes work but not sure where's the issue. The links for the **first 2 classes** don't work and I cannot click on to open linked pages.

Here's the HTML:

```css
footer {
    width: calc(100%-80px);
    padding: 40px 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer ul {
    width: fit-content;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

footer ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Catamaran';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.footer-links-news {
    display: none;
}

.footer-sm {
    width: 50px;
    float:right;
}

.footer-sm  img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
    <ul class="footer-links-main">
      <li><a href="project4.html"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="developer.html"></a>Developer</li>
      <li><a href="https://poly.google.com/view/dKsT1ZCKsqX" target="_blank"></a>Vietnam Virtual Tour</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.pexels.com/search/Hanoi/" target="_blank"></a>Hanoi Photo Gallery</li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"></a>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="footer-links-news">
      <li>Lastest News on Vietnam News</li>
      <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/" target="_blank"></a>Soptlights</li>
      <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/economy" target="_blank"></a>Economy</li>
      <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/life-style" target="_blank"></a>Life & Style</li>
      <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/environment" target="_blank"></a>Enviroment</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer-sm">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="Images/plugsin-icon-yt.png" alt="Youtube Icon">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="Images/plugsin-icon-fb.png" alt="Facebook Icon">
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="Images/plugsin-icon-tt.png" alt="Twitter Icon">
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the link needs to go inside the anchor:

```html
<!-- this -->
<a href="project4.html">Home</a>

<!-- not this -->
<a href="project4.html"></a>Home
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need the anchor to actual contain something so it is clickable.

```
   <ul class="footer-links-main">
      <li><a href="project4.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="developer.html">Developer</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text should be between `<a href="">HERE</a>` tags

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="footer-links-main">
    <li><a href="project4.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="developer.html">Developer</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://poly.google.com/view/dKsT1ZCKsqX" target="_blank">Vietnam Virtual Tour</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.pexels.com/search/Hanoi/" target="_blank">Hanoi Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html"></a>Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="footer-links-news">
    <li>Lastest News on Vietnam News</li>
    <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/" target="_blank">Soptlights</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/economy" target="_blank">Economy</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/life-style" target="_blank">Life & Style</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://vietnamnews.vn/environment" target="_blank">Enviroment</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```